# Como contar las cadenas de caracteres de un data frame y ponerlo en el dataframeoriginal

Tags: python, array, pandas, apply

Agradezco su ayuda con esta situación:

1. Quiero contar los caracteres de cada uno de los registros de un data frame Ejemplo:
   saludo = "Counselor, Log Cabin Ranch"
   caracteres = len(saludo)
   print(caracteres)
   26

En phyton por medio de una funcion , ya que lo quiero aplicar a una columna completa de un dataframe , intente por medio de una funcion

def contar(x):
for i in x:
caracteres = len(x)
print(caracteres)

y Luego quiero agregar una columna nueva a mi dataframe principal con el resultado de esa lista de conteo:

sal['len'] = sal['JobTitle'].apply(contar);

Esta parte me trae el conteo en una lista , como lo necesito
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que en el data frame resultante los registros de esta nueva columna me salen None

[image: Dataframe resultante]

Agradezco su colaboración

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Hay una forma más fácil de hacer lo que quieres

Las columnas tienen un método `str` (String) para evaluar su contenido y los `string` tienen un método `len()` que devuelve el número de caracteres del `string`

Puedes hacer esto:

```
sal['len'] = sal['JobTitle'].str.len()
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias ;D